# get process name from process ID in a c/cpp program (I can't use /proc/<pid>/cmdline)

Tags: c++, c, linux, pid

I know this question has been asked a few times, but unfortunately  I haven't been able to find an answer that matches my restrictions.

I have a PID (***not*** my process), and I want to find its name. Now, I can't access `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` (restrictions), and I can't find a way to get the output of `ps` in my program, besides sending its output to a file and then parsing it (which I need to avoid).

Is there another option?

I am coding in Linux/Android user space in C/C++

Comment: argv[0] should contain your full process name.

Comment: `ps` use parsing of `/proc`, so if you can't access to `/proc/PID/cmdline`, you also can't see it in output of `ps`!

Comment: @ismail Thanks for the comment, I just realized that I made a mistake in my description, so I am terribly sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `ps` *does* work (?) but you can't write to a temporary file. (Why? Maybe AppArmor is restricting access to just some processes?)

*If* that's true, then you can use a pipe to read the `ps` output directly into your program, without a temporary file.

```
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);

int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  // child
  close(fds[0]);  // close the read end of the pipe in the child
  dup2(1,fds[1]); // move the write end to be stdout
  close(fds[1]);

  execlp("ps", "ps", "-p", "blah", NULL);
} else {
  // parent
  close(fds[1]);  // close the write end of the pipe in the parent.

  // read data from fds[0] here

  close(fds[0]);
  int status;
  wait(&status); // clean up the zombie ps process
}
```

That example leaves out all the error checking (which you *must* add), and might not be allowed (depending what the nature of your access restrictions might be).

Comment: +1 but major bug and minor nit: `execlp( "ps", "ps", "-p", ...)`.  Should specify "ps" twice.

Comment: @ams Aww man, I wish there was a more simple solution.
ps does work, but I need to set some security restrictions statically and I can't really know the PID (to access /proc/<PID>) in advance but only in runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamPursell well spotted.

Comment: @just_a_user Well, by C standards this *is* a simple solution. The PID thing is no problem; `ps` can list all processes, and you just search for the one you need.

Comment: After discussing the restrictions, I am allowed to check /proc/<PID> dynamically. In any case, thank you @ams.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android, and you do not have root permission, you can try with this function:

```
public static String getAppName(Context ctx, int PID){
    ActivityManager mng
               = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : mng.getRunningAppProcesses()){
        if(processInfo.pid == PID){
            return processInfo.processName;
        }
    }
    return "not found PID";
}
```

Comment: Hey @invictus1306
Unfortunately, I am restricted to C/C++. Thanks!